# Angular preflight response error when accessing external url

Tags: angularjs, json

I m a using angularJs and I need access a external url.

The  external url will be used to get zip code informations.

The url has the next format: https://viacep.com.br/ws/{zipcode}/json/

Sample: https://viacep.com.br/ws/23020180/json/
I have used the next, but I always get an error.

I have tried w/o $sce  and/or included headers, but no success.

If I use Postman I get the correct result:

```
{
  "cep": "01001-000",
  "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
  "complemento": "lado ímpar",
  "bairro": "Sé",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
}
```

But with my code, I get an error:

//error:

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://viacep.com.br/ws/23020180/json/. 
Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

    angular.js:14328 Possibly unhandled rejection:
    {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":{},"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true","Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type, X-Request-With, X-Requested-By","Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET, OPTIONS","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VsadfsdW8iLCJpYXQiOjE0OTQ1Mzg4ODN9.JOUl55vmscTSGc2XWWi0fRGYdPKJSZDOSlRUBdStHvU"}},"statusText":""}
```

//front end markup

```
var trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
   };

  $scope.findCEP=function(){
     var viaCepUrl = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/23020180/json/";
     $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url:trustSrc(viaCepUrl),
         headers:{'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'true',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type, X-Request-With, X-Requested-By',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}
         }
     ).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Allow CORS in your server config.

Comment: Hi, I have a mongo server with cors enabled, but I am not acessing resources from my mongo server. Its a external url from third site. I have no control of the external site. But, the url works with Postman, if you want to test

Comment: `X-Request-With` should be `X-Requested-With`

Comment: Hi, X-Requested-With makes no difference. The error continues.

Comment: I think you running your angular code in index.html. Try to put it in a server.

Comment: I figured out. My problem is with my Interceptor auth. It was adding auth header. Here is: angular.module('clinang').factory('AuthInterceptor', function AuthInterceptor(AuthTokenFactory) {
  'use strict';
  return {
    request: addToken
  };

  function addToken(config) {
    var token = AuthTokenFactory.getToken();
    if (token) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }
    return config;
  }
});

Comment: Is there a way to avoid set auth to specific urls?

Comment: You can try http:\\username:password@myurl.com. You need to create authString acceptor in your server to pass it with ajax call.

Comment: Thank you Mr hurricane, I just solved it

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly the same sort of problem I cam across a few weeks back. Unfortunately, things are not that easy. There is a very good CORS documentation [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). It really helped me resolve my problems.

The main idea is that there are 2 type of requests: simple request ans complex requests. Now, if we speak about simple requests, those don't get preflighted. In order for a request to be considered as simple by most browsers it have GET or POST as methods and the only allowed custom header that are allowed to be manually set are the following:

Accept,
Accept-Language,
Content-Language,
Content-Type (but note the additional requirements below),
DPR,
Downlink,
Save-Data,
Viewport-Width,
Width,

The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
multipart/form-data,
text/plain,

In my case I did the following:

```
httpRequest.open('POST', "https://s2events.andSoOn.net", true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
//httpRequest.setRequestHeader("From", "my@email.com")
httpRequest.send(JsonWebhookData);
```

So I have commented out my "From" header. From that moment, my request was sent without the preflight check and problem was resolved. So try taking out all the custom headers that are not necessarily needed. Most of the headers you use are CORS specific and are normally set by the browser, according to the documentation I shared at the start. Hope it helps.